# application.doubleclick

Tags: excel, vba

i need to double click on a cell.and looks like its getting edited.this is needed because i am pasting a date to cell .but it is not getting formatted as date .so if i double click it its getting formatted as date .(this is a manual work and i need it automated.

i tried using application . doubleclick method.

```
Cells(i, "AW").Select
Application.doubleclick
Cells(i, "AX").Select
```

for example,if the date i "26-08-19 23:45",when i double click it it becomes "26-08-2019  23:45:00"

Comment: Try This `Cells(i, "AW").Formula = Cells(i, "AW").Value`

Comment: Sounds like a strange workaround. Have you tried adjusting the formatting of your cell? Also if you're pasting it with code, try and wrap it in a `format` (or `text` for formulas) statement to get it to display right. These would both be better solutions than to get Excel to double click and sort itself out.

Comment: It would help if you provided more information about where the data being pasted into the cell is coming from, and what format the date string has. Could you explain further? Perhaps you could provide the code that is doing the actual paste into the cell(s) where the problem is.

Comment: i tried format method but it didn't work .only way i could change it was bu double clicking it.i have posted a before about pasting the value form a textbox using `cells(i,"AW").value = textbox6.value`

Comment: did you try what i suggested? You need to paste that line after your paste code...

Comment: You could use `cells(i,"AW").value = cDate( textbox6.value )`, but you will need to add validation logic to check that the date conversion is valid. Is the date typed in by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion. Use a validation function that is called to check the value entered into Textbox6 is a valid date and if so, update the cell with the date. Below is sample code which you may need to adapt. If you are collecting lots of dates in many text boxes then you would need to have multiple `_Change` functions, one for each box, or alternatively do the validation all in one go after a button click or similar user action:

```
Private Function CheckDate(tb As MSForms.TextBox) As Variant
    CheckDate = ""
    Dim dd As Date
    On Error Resume Next
    dd = CDate(tb.Text)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        tb.BackColor = vbYellow
    ElseIf Year(dd) < 1900 Then
        tb.BackColor = vbYellow
    Else
        tb.BackColor = vbWhite
        CheckDate = dd
    End If
End Function

Private Sub TextBox6_Change()
    Me.Range("D9").Value = CheckDate(TextBox6)
End Sub
```

Empty box:

[image: Textbox 6 empty]

Valid date entered:

[image: Valid date entered]

Many formats of date are supported

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are pasting from a textbox try and force format it as the correct date right away:

```vb
Format(Sheet1.TextBox6.Value, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```